# Magento data migration from 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: magento2, data-migration, magento-2.3

i'm deploying an update to one of my store from Magento 2.3 to 2.4, i will also deploy a new template/layout.

I'm doing this new 2.4 version and the template in a different server. I would like to know what is the best way to migrate the data associated with customers, orders and products.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For a hassle-free migration, you can try using a migration extension/SaaS migration tool like ours. It doesn't cost much but saves you lots of time figuring it out on your own.

Comment: Hi...does it work from 2.3 to 2.4 ? Regards

Comment: Yes, it does. You can check out the Magento Upgrade supported versions and other details on our website.